# Convert Response from HTTP request to PNG in a picturebox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I make a request to a web server using

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
string result = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

and get the following format returned in "result" how do i change it to a PNG I can display in a picturebox?

```
aPic = "�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\00\0\0\00\b\u0006\0\0\0W\u0002��\0\0\0\u001dtEXtjira-system-image-type\0avatar�\u0002\u001aa\0\0\u0010�IDATx��Y�W�Y�����>s�Lw�S3�5eL\0\u0001�EY\u0015YeM\u0002a\rdO\bd\u000f!\u0010�}S\u0016\u00196q-\u0005�\u0005\u0010\u0005�...
```

I'm using .Net 4.0 and this is a winforms app.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `StreamReader` is so wrong choice to receive **binary** data.

Comment: Dont read it as string, but read it as byte array. Then you can create Image using that byte array.

Comment: @Sinatr its a very common mistake i wish MS had given that class a better name as everyone assumes it the best way to read a stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PNG is a bitmap image saved with a PNG compression format, so you need to look at bitmaps not PNG, and if you look at the bitmap class then you will see that it has a constructor that accepts a stream (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw(v=vs.110).aspx))

this then gives you a nice example

```
private void InitializeStreamBitmap()
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest request = 
            System.Net.WebRequest.Create(
            "http://www.microsoft.com//h/en-us/r/ms_masthead_ltr.gif");
        System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream responseStream = 
            response.GetResponseStream();
        Bitmap bitmap2 = new Bitmap(responseStream);
        PictureBox1.Image = bitmap2;

    }
    catch(System.Net.WebException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error opening the image file."
           + "Check the URL");
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW thanks for the quick response and the help, this was what fitted most easily in to what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Download data as byte array and convert it to image and put it in pictureBox:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
  using (var stream = webClient.OpenRead("http://1.2.3.4/image.png"))
  {
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(stream);
  }
}
```

Comment: the OP is already obtaining the stream from the request, seems a bit wasteful to copy from the steam to a new memory stream just to load the image from the stream

Comment: Great Edit, much more succinct now, even better than the MS example I provided